# Design a multiple Asp.Net Core apps Solution

Tags: design, testing, validation, asp.net-core

I am having an .Net Core Solution consisting of 3 Projects:

- The Site (Asp.Net Core MVC WebApp)
- The API (Asp.Net Core API)
- The "Common" library for shared functionality.

The Common library contains all the business logic in form of Services. These Services are used by both web projects (registered inside their `Startup` classes). So the two web projects are more or less wrappers for calls into the Services. For example a Profile Action on the UsersController in the MVC app will just call the GetById(int id) method of the injected UsersService, put the result into its UserProfileViewModel and render the view.

##### Model Validation

The Common Library contains the Business Models somewhat representing the database structure. The API has its own (versioned) set of Contract Models and the Site also has its own View Models. That makes a sum of three different model types (sometimes representing the same entity):

- Business Models
- API Contract Models
- Site View Models

`DataAnnotations` are currently used on all Models for validation so first the controller action does the validation and if it succeeds the Contract/View Model is mapped to the required Business Model and this is then passed into Service method. The Service method itself also performs validation by calling `Validator.TryValidateObject` and throwing an exception if validation fails. Now in a lot of cases this seems overkill especially if the validation is costly and models are created often.

##### Testing

There are integration tests against the Services. Also there are tests against the API (using HttpClient) but since an API action methods mostly are just a thin wrapper around a call of a Service method whats effectively being tested there is that the passed in model is valid. This also does not seem the best way of going about it.

Can this design be improved?

Comment: I'd recommend looking into FluentValidation:  https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/aspnet.html#getting-started

Comment: Thanks @BenCottrell for your comment. I understand that fluentvalidation separates the object to be validated from the validator itself but I can't really see how this would improve or simplify the design. I still would need a validator for each of my many models and probably have multiple validations happening on different stages (in the Controller, in the Service). Or am I missing something here?